# Looking for ways to optimize the program [Scala/Spark]

Tags: scala, apache-spark, math

I have an RDD which look the following:

> ( (tag_1, set_1), (tag_2, set_2) ) , ... , ( (tag_M, set_M), (tag_L, set_L) ), ...

And for each pair from the RDD I'm going to compute the expression

[image: expression]

for k=0,..,3 and to find the sum: p(0)+...p(3). For each pair of pairs n_1 is length of the set in the first pair and n_2 is length of the set in the second pair.

For now I wrote the following:

```
val N = 1000
pairRDD.map({
    case ((t1,l1), (t2,l2)) => (t1,t2, {
      val n_1 = l1.size
      val n_2 = l2.size
      val vals = (0 to 3).map(k => {
        val P1 = (0 to (n_2-k-1))
          .map(j => 1 - n_1/(N-j.toDouble))
          .foldLeft(1.0)(_*_)
        val P2 = (0 to (k-1))
          .map(j => (n_1-j.toDouble)*(n_2-j.toDouble)/(N-n_2+k.toDouble-j.toDouble)/(k.toDouble-j.toDouble) )
          .foldLeft(1.0)(_*_)
        P1*P2
      })
      vals.sum.toDouble 
    })
  })
```

The problem is it seems to work really slow and I hope there are some features of scala/spark that I don't know about and that could reduce the time of execution there.

Edit:

1) In the first place I have a csv-file with 2 columns: tag and message_id. For each tag I'm finding messages where it could be found and creating pairs like I described above (tagIdsZipped). The code is [here](https://pastebin.com/kcmLPexb)

2) Then I want to compute the expression for each pair and write it down to file.
Actually, I also would like to filter the result, but it would be even longer, so I'm even not trying for now.

3) No, actually I dont, but the problems happened, when I tried to use this code, previously I did the following:

```
val tagPairsWithMeasure: RDD[(Tag, Tag, Measure)] = tagIdsZipped.map({
    case ((t1,l1), (t2,l2)) => (t1,t2, {
      val numer = l1.intersect(l2).size
      val denom = Math.sqrt(l1.size)*Math.sqrt(l2.size)
      numer.toDouble / denom
    })
  })
```

and everything worked fine. (see 4) )

4) In the file I described in 1) there are about 25million rows (~1.2 GB). I'm computing in on Xeon E5-2673 @2.4GHz and 32 GB RAM. It took about 1.5h to execute the code with the function I described in 3). I see, that there are more operations now, but it took about 3hours and only about 25% of the task was done. The main problem is I will have to work with about 3 times more data, but I can't even do it on a 'smaller' one.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You could replace `foldLeft(1.0)(_ * _)` by `product` (won't buy you much), you could omit some `toDouble` here and there (won't buy you any performance either), you could try to do some really annoying micro-optimization, and maybe manually unroll the `4`-step loops. But it all won't have too much impact on performance, because your computation is embarassingly parallel: it's a single `map` where each element is processed independently, no complicated shuffles that could be optimized, nothing fancy going on at all... So, from Spark's point of view, I don't see much room for optimization here.

Comment: Maybe you should add some information: 1) How do you get this `pairRDD` in the first place? 2) What happens with the result of the `map`? As it is, it doesn't do anything, because there are no actions. 3) Do you *know* that it is this particular step that takes most of the time? 4) How much data and processing power are you talking about, and what exactly do you mean by "really slow".

Comment: @Andrey Tyukin, thank you very much for your answer! I added some more information to my post, it would be great, if you could check it out.

Answer (score 0):

As has been mentioned there is not much to improve about Spark.
The biggest issue I can see here is using `range.map`.

`(0 to (n_2-k-1))` creates a `Range` object.
Calling `map` on it creates a `Vector` allocating much memory.

The most simple solution is to work with iterators since `foldLeft` is a streaming-friendly function:
`(0 to (n_2-k-1)).iterator` instead of `(0 to (n_2-k-1))`

It also probably makes sense to try rewriting it imperatively using `var`s, loops and arrays since since computation inside a loop is extremely cheap. But it is a weapon of the last chance.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using dataframes?
maybe you can create a dataframe with a schema like this:

```
tagIdsDF
+-----------------------------+
|tag1  | set1  |tag2  | set2  |
+-----------------------------+
|tag_1 |set_1  |tag_2 |set_2  |
|...                          |
|tag_M |set_M  |tag_L |set_L  |
+-----------------------------+
```

and define a UDF to compute the sum:

```
val pFun = udf((l1:Seq[Double], l2:Seq[Double]) => {
     val n_1 = l1.size
     val n_2 = l2.size
     val vals = (0 to 3).map(k => {
       val P1 = (0 to (n_2-k-1))
          .map(j => 1 - n_1/(N-j.toDouble))
          .foldLeft(1.0)(_*_)
       val P2 = (0 to (k-1))
          .map(j => (n_1-j.toDouble)*(n_2-j.toDouble)/(N-n_2+k.toDouble-j.toDouble)/(k.toDouble-j.toDouble) )
          .foldLeft(1.0)(_*_)
        P1*P2
     })
     vals.sum.toDouble 
})
```

notice that you don't need to pass tag_1/tag_2 because this information is on the resulting dataframe, then you can call it like this:

```
val tagWithMeasureDF = tagIdsDF.withColumn("measure", pFun($"set1", $"set2"))
```

and you get this df:

```
tagWithMeasureDF
+-----------------------------+---------+
|tag1  | set1  |tag2  | set2  | measure |
+---------------------------------------+
|tag_1 |set_1  |tag_2 |set_2  |   m1    |
|...              ...                ...|
|tag_M |set_M  |tag_L |set_L  |   mn    |
+---------------------------------------+
```

doing something like this maybe helps you to achieve the desired performance.

Hope this helps you and if it works tell me!